# SQL Server Unique Key Constraint Date/Time Span

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

How can I set a unique key constraint for the following table to ensure the date/time span between the Date/BeginTime and Date/EndTime do not overlap with another record? If I need to add a computed column, what data type and calculation?

```
Column Name   Data Type
Date          date
BeginTime     time(7)
EndTime       time(7)
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted some of your code.

Comment: Should have made this clear in my initial post.  I am looking to ensure the rows in the table are unique based on the Date, BeginTime, and EndTIme values in the table.  If this is not possible in the SQL Server table using contraints then I will add the necessary code in the business logic layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that you can do that using a UNIQUE constraint in SQL Server. Postgres has this capability, but to implement it in SQL Server you must use a trigger. Since your question was "how can I do this using a unique key constraint", the correct answer is "you can't". If you had asked "how can I enforce this non-overlapping constraint", there is an answer.

Comment: I think You Cant is a good answer in the context of the question.

Comment: @SqlSurfer, Alexander Kuznetsov shows one possible way. [Storing intervals of time with no overlaps](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/03/08/storing-intervals-of-time-with-no-overlaps.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Alexander Kuznetsov shows one possible way. [Storing intervals of time with no overlaps](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/03/08/storing-intervals-of-time-with-no-overlaps.aspx).

See also article by Joe Celko: [Contiguous Time Periods](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/contiguous-time-periods/)

Here is the table and the first interval:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.IntegerSettings(SettingID INT NOT NULL,
  IntValue INT NOT NULL,
  StartedAt DATETIME NOT NULL,
  FinishedAt DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PreviousFinishedAt DATETIME NULL,

  CONSTRAINT PK_IntegerSettings_SettingID_FinishedAt 
      PRIMARY KEY(SettingID, FinishedAt),

  CONSTRAINT UNQ_IntegerSettings_SettingID_PreviousFinishedAt
      UNIQUE(SettingID, PreviousFinishedAt),

  CONSTRAINT FK_IntegerSettings_SettingID_PreviousFinishedAt
    FOREIGN KEY(SettingID, PreviousFinishedAt)
    REFERENCES dbo.IntegerSettings(SettingID, FinishedAt),

  CONSTRAINT CHK_IntegerSettings_PreviousFinishedAt_NotAfter_StartedAt
      CHECK(PreviousFinishedAt <= StartedAt),

  CONSTRAINT CHK_IntegerSettings_StartedAt_Before_FinishedAt 
      CHECK(StartedAt < FinishedAt)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.IntegerSettings
    (SettingID, IntValue, StartedAt, FinishedAt, PreviousFinishedAt)
VALUES(1, 1, '20070101', '20070103', NULL);
```

Constraints enforce these rules:

- There can be only one first interval for a setting
- Next window must begin after the end of the previous one
- Two different windows cannot refer to one and the same window as their previous one

Comment: This requires the addition of the PreviousFinishedAT value, which means that the structure is not in first normal form, because that column does not depend on the key value for this record. It also correctly "enforces" the constraint **only** if you fetch the previous value and provide it correctly: aka there is no actual enforcement.

Comment: @cliffordheath, In [Contiguous Time Periods](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/contiguous-time-periods/) Joe Celko writes: "The `previous_end_date` column feels strange at first. It seems redundant. But I will argue that it is not. A row in a table should model a complete fact. That is why we have `(current_start_date , current_end_date)` pairs; together, they tell us about the duration of the task as a whole thing; there is no need to read another row to find the ending date."

Comment: Interesting. I'm surprised that Celko supports that approach. Really, it's a hack to work around the absence of a non-overlapping constraint in SQL, and I stand by my claim. I like the Postgres solution much better - it also handles a variety of other problems too.

Comment: @cliffordheath, Of course, it is a "hack", a "clever technique", because SQL Server doesn't have the temporal features that Postgres has. I just wanted to point out that there is such technique. I believe you that in Postges this could be done in a much simpler way.

Comment: A "clever technique" should not break the rules of normalisation. I call it a hack because it does - and it still doesn't actually enforce the constraint. if you're going to rely on procedural code being correct anyway, there's no need for this phoney "enforcement".

Comment: @cliffordheath, I don't want to argue about normalization. But what procedural code are you talking about? The whole point of this exercise is to avoid triggers and have only declarative constraints. This set of constraints doesn't allow you to create two overlapping intervals. They work together to enforce the rule: no overlapping intervals. Do you think that with these constraints in place it is still possible to put overlapping intervals into the table?

Comment: When you insert (after the first row), where does the previous_end_date come from? It is not calculated by the INSERT statement. Ok, I now see that it's enforced by the FK. Fair enough; but procedural code must still have fetched it first. So I take it back; the constraint is enforced, but it's awkward (and requires an extra index).

Comment: And if you want discontiguous but non-overlapping time periods, it still doesn't work. The OP did not specify contiguous time (just non-overlapping), so this solution doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @cliffordheath, As Alexander Kuznetsov wrote in his post, `CHECK(PreviousFinishedAt <= StartedAt)` allows for gaps, i.e. discontinuous periods. If it is replaced with a stricter constraint `CHECK(PreviousFinishedAt = StartedAt)`, then gaps are prohibited.

Comment: But if you use the <= check, then you cannot have foreign key enforcement, so you can provide any value. Again, you're back to dependent on the code being correct. At least Celko got this part right.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91812/discussion-between-vladimir-baranov-and-cliffordheath).

Comment: For those following along, in our discussion we concluded that this only works on MS-SQL because that doesn't have a standard SQL implementation of NULL in indexes. If you can insert more than one record with a NULL previous_end_date (as in Oracle, PG and other standard SQLs), then all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- this is a unique key that allows for null in EndTime field
--  This Unique Index could be clusteres optionally instead of the traditional primary key being clustered 
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX  
[UNQ_IDX_Date_BeginTm_EndTm_UniqueIndex_With_Null_EndTime] ON [MyTableName]
(
    [Date] ASC,
    [BeginTime] ASC,
    [EndTime] ASC
) 

GO


-- this is a traditional PK Constraint that is clustered but EndTime is
--- Not Null
-- it is possible that this table would not have a traditional Primary Key
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Date_BeginTm_EndTm_EndTimeIsNotNull PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    Date,
    BeginTime,
    EndTime
    ) 

GO

-- HINT - Control your BeginTime and EndTime secconds and milliseconds at 
-- all insert and read points 
-- you want 13:01:42.000  and 13:01:42.333  to evaluate and compare the
-- exact way you expect from a KEY perspective
```

Comment: This Answer is all that you can do by just defining the keys.  cliffordheaths Answer is actually a better answer to what you are probably trying to accomplish.  I always use stored procs and transactions to enforce this scenario as cliffordheath suggest.  (I prefer app level logic to triggers)